# firebase cloud function timeout and deploy using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to the whole cloud functions thing , I have two questions , first is the timeout for the function is really just 60 second ? and why is that , and second how can I deploy the cloud function always ? will it charge more ? can anyone explain this to me ? I have write the post in typescript but should I deploy it every 60s its not a solution ! what should I do ? I'm working on flutter app .
should I deploy the function using the cloud-function package ? I'm so confused !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have two questions , first is the timeout for the function is really just 60 second ?

Yes.

> and why is that

A reason is not given anywhere in the documentation.  However, it's a sensible place to start for the sort of work that's expected to be performed in Cloud Functions.  It's definitely not intended for long-running work.

> how can I deploy the cloud function always ? will it charge more ? can anyone explain this to me ?

I think you are confused about what a timeout is.  It's not the amount of time that a function stays deployed.  Once deployed, it still stay deployed forever.  The timeout refers to the amount of time it will spend processing a single event before shutting down that one invocation.

Comment: thanks for the explanation , iam new to cloud function and yeah it seems that i have understood the timeout term in a bad way thanks soo much for the explanation